# regular expression in oracle to get a range of ip address from 100.64.*.* to 100.127.*.*?

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get a range of IP address from 100.64.*.* to 100.127.*.*

If i have table named testIp and column named PRIVATE_IP_ADDR and below are the records present:

```
1) 100.63.22.55 
2) 100.64.102.558 
3) 100.123.22.12 
4) 100.127.22.55 
5) 100.128.221.55
6) 100.125.355.10
7) 100.64.102.254
```

requirements:

```
  1. 2nd part of ip should be from 64 to 127 range
    2. 3rd part of ip should be from 0 to 255 range
    3. 4th part of ip should be from 0 to 255 range
```

regular expression should pick the below ip address

```
3) 100.123.22.12 
4) 100.127.22.55 
7) 100.64.102.254
```

what i have tried till now is :

```
    select * from testip where REGEXP_LIKE (PRIVATE_IP_ADDR , '^(100\.
(6[4-9]|[7-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-7])\.
([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.
([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-5][0-5]))' ) ;

but when i tried the result is 

2) 100.64.102.558 
3) 100.123.22.12 
4) 100.127.22.55 
7) 100.64.102.254
```

> i dont want the record

`2)100.64.102.558`

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have only IP addresses here? Will they always be valid? Have you tried anything already?

Comment: i have a coloum of ip addresses in a table which are valid. so i want all the ip address from the table which are in between those range.

Comment: The most important thing to learn about regular expressions is when NOT to use them.  That usually includes *semantic* (as opposed to *syntactic*) matching.  Just parse the address (perhaps with regex) and then check whether it fits your business rules, whether that's a stored procedure in oracle or in your app code (or in Patrick's example, in a further select).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regular Expression for IPv4 addresses**

Certainly for IPv4 addresses, you could use a regular expression and just pick the second set of digits.

Here I use the escape charater, `\d`, for digits. The `2` in the regular expression just indicates that we want the second occurence of a set of digits.

Finally, I cast the value as a number and use the between operator.

```
       SCOTT@db>list
      1  WITH t AS
      2    (SELECT '100.127.22.55' ip_address FROM dual
      3    UNION ALL
      4    SELECT '100.66.22.55' FROM dual
      5    UNION ALL
      6    SELECT '100.123.22.12' FROM dual
      7    UNION ALL
      8      SELECT '100.63.22.55' FROM dual
      9    )
     10  SELECT *
     11  FROM
     12    (SELECT t.ip_address,
     13      regexp_substr(t.ip_address, '^\d+',1,1) first_number,
     14      to_number(regexp_substr(t.ip_address, '\d+',1,2)) second_number
     15    FROM t
     16    )
     17  WHERE 1=1
     18  AND first_number = '100'
     19* AND second_number BETWEEN 66 AND 127
    SCOTT@db>/

    IP_ADDRESS    FIRST_NUMBER                                         SECOND_NUMBER
    ------------- ---------------------------------------------------- -------------
    100.123.22.12 100                                                            123
    100.127.22.55 100                                                            127
    100.66.22.55  100                                                            66
```

**Update based on op comments**

To take a regexp_like approach (and take into consideration how the question has been more extensively described), a solution follows.  One needs to be very careful when using quantifiers and I found using anchors helpful:

```
SCOTT@db>WITH t AS
  2    (SELECT '100.63.22.55' ip_address FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT '100.64.102.558' ip_address FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT '100.123.22.12' ip_address FROM dual
  7    UNION ALL
  8    SELECT '100.127.22.55' ip_address FROM dual
  9    UNION ALL
 10    SELECT '100.128.221.55' ip_address FROM dual
 11    UNION ALL
 12    SELECT '100.125.355.10' ip_address FROM dual
 13    UNION ALL
 14    SELECT '100.64.102.254' ip_address FROM dual
 15    )
 16  SELECT *
 17  FROM t
 18  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (t.ip_address , '^100\.(6[4-9]|[7-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-7])(\.([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))){2}$')
 19  /

IP_ADDRESS
--------------
100.123.22.12
100.127.22.55
100.64.102.254
```

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE (PRIVATE_IP_ADDR , '^(100\.
(6[4-9]|[7-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-7])\.
([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.
([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-5][0-5]))' ) ; `

this type of answer would be better

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me hours of research.